# How do I choose "All languages" while scraping TripAdvisor's reviews?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Python programming and scrapy as well. I have been trying to scrape some reviews from www.tripadvisor.com. It appears, for some hotels, there are reviews in non-English languages, and when I use the following code, I only get the ratings for English languages:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import re


class ReviewScrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'review_scrape'
allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60970-d226251-Reviews-Murfreesboro_Extended_Stay_Hotel-Murfreesboro_Tennessee.html']

def parse(self, response):
    hotel_name = response.xpath('//div[@class="ui_column is-12-tablet is-10-mobile hotelDescription"]/h1[@id="HEADING"]/text()').extract_first()
    for href in response.xpath('//div[starts-with(@class,"quote")]/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'hotel_name':hotel_name}, callback=self.parse_reviews)
    url = response.url
    if not re.findall(r'or\d', url):
        next_page = re.sub(r'(-Reviews-)', r'\g<1>or5-', url)
    else:
        pagenum = int(re.findall(r'or(\d+)-', url)[0])
        pagenum_next = pagenum + 5
        next_page = url.replace('or' + str(pagenum), 'or' + str(pagenum_next))
    yield scrapy.Request(
        next_page,
        meta={'dont_redirect': True},
        callback=self.parse)

def parse_reviews(self, response):
    rating = response.xpath('//div[@class="ui_column is-10-desktop is-12-tablet is-12-mobile"]/span[@class]').extract_first()[-11:-9]
    date = response.xpath('//*[@class="ratingDate"]/text()').extract_first()
    yield {
            'hotels_name':response.meta['hotel_name'],
            'rating':rating,
            'date': date
            }
```

However, later I realized that by default the review languages are set to "English". So every time I close and reopen my browser, and then open the reviews page of a hotel, the language is set to English. Please Check the following picture:

[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK4bE.png)

My question is how do I select the "All languages" option in my code so that I can scrape reviews of all languages? I would highly appreciate your help. I have tried every way possible, but couldn't solve the problem. I am looking forward to your help. Thanks

Comment: did you try`DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS` in your setting file?

Comment: Try to analyse the request which is being sent on clicking 'all languages'. And then try to simulate the same request with all the headers and parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the answer is a bit late, but for others interested:
You can easily do so by throwing

"?filterLang=ALL"

at the end of the URL and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day, and my student's master work.