# rvest: language selection not working in tripadvisor

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am facing a web scraping problem. I intend to scrape few comments on tripadvisor. I would like to use `rvest` and to get comments in all languages. From [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903259/how-do-i-choose-all-languages-while-scraping-tripadvisors-reviews) I understood that a possible way was to use `?filterLang=ALL` at the end of the url. In a web browser, it does work. Example:

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d2013853-Reviews-114_Faubourg-Paris_Ile_de_France.html?filterLang=ALL

Does provide comments with "All languages" selected (and you can see a lot of french comments). Here is my problem: I try to get comment' titles:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d2013853-Reviews-114_Faubourg-Paris_Ile_de_France.html?filterLang=ALL"

reviews_html <- read_html(url)

reviews_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//span[@class='noQuotes']") %>%
  html_text()

 [1] "I've never visited this restaurant," "Perfect"                            
 [3] "Memorable experience"                "Tasty"                              
 [5] "Absolutely spectacular"              "Excellent"                          
 [7] "Wonderfullll"                        "A Perfect Evening"                  
 [9] "Dinner "                             "Perfect dinner and evening"
```

I only got the English ones. And here the weird thing: if I try to get the number of pages:

```
reviews_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@data-tab='TABS_REVIEWS']//a[@data-page-number]")%>%
  html_text()

[1] "Next" "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "176"
```

I have the number of comment pages corresponding to "All languages" selection! If you compare with the case without language selection

```
url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d2013853-Reviews-114_Faubourg-Paris_Ile_de_France.html"

reviews_html <- read_html(url)

reviews_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//span[@class='noQuotes']") %>%
  html_text()

 [1] "I've never visited this restaurant," "Perfect"                            
 [3] "Memorable experience"                "Tasty"                              
 [5] "Absolutely spectacular"              "Excellent"                          
 [7] "Wonderfullll"                        "A Perfect Evening"                  
 [9] "Dinner "                             "Perfect dinner and evening"
```

I get the same comments, but:

```
reviews_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@data-tab='TABS_REVIEWS']//a[@data-page-number]")%>%
  html_text()

[1] "Next" "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "61"
```

I get the number of pages corresponding to the English language selection.
I tried setting also the cookies:

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d2013853-Reviews-114_Faubourg-Paris_Ile_de_France.html?filterLang=ALL"
httr::GET(url, 
          set_cookies(`TALanguage` = "ALL",
                      `Domain` = ".tripadvisor.com"))%>%
  read_html()%>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//span[@class='noQuotes']") %>%
  html_text()
```

But it did not work either.
Does anyone understand what is going on, and what I could do to actually get the comments in all languages with rvest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the filter manually, there is a `POST` call on the same url. Setting `filterLang=ALL` in the form body correctly returns the data :

```r
library(rvest)
library(httr)

reviews_html <- POST(
    "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d2013853-Reviews-114_Faubourg-Paris_Ile_de_France.html",
    add_headers('x-requested-with'= 'XMLHttpRequest'),
    body = list(
      preferFriendReviews = "FALSE",
      t = "",
      q = "", # filter by mention, try "france"
      filterSeasons = "", # "1" is mar-may / "2" is jun-aug / "3" is sep-nov / "4" is dec-feb
      filterLang = "ALL", # try "zhCN" or "fr"
      filterSafety = "FALSE",
      filterSegment = "", # "3" is families / "2" is couples / "5" is solo / "1" is business / "4" is friends
      trating = "", # stars: "5" / "4" / "3" / "2" / "1" / "0"
      isLastPoll = "false",
      changeSet = "REVIEW_LIST"
    ), 
    encode = "form") %>%
    read_html()

reviews <- reviews_html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//span[@class='noQuotes']") %>%
    html_text()

print(reviews)

pages  <- reviews_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@data-tab='TABS_REVIEWS']//a[@data-page-number]")%>%
  html_text()

print(pages)
```

In the above code, I've added some description about the fields if you need those filters

[kaggle link](https://www.kaggle.com/bertrandmartel/tripadvisor-reviews)

Output:

```
 [1] "I've never visited this restaurant," "Excellente expérience"              
 [3] "Du grand art"                        "Promesse tenue"                     
 [5] "Une soirée de rêve en famille"       "Délicieux !!! "                     
 [7] "Une expérience inoubliable"          "UN CERTAIN REGARD"                  
 [9] "Excellent soiree en couple"          "Une soirée magnifique"              
[1] "Next" "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "176"
```

Comment: Thanks ! Perfect with the filter description. Do you have any idea why the url did not the trick ?

Comment: @denis in fact, the behaviour in R is correct, when you open an incognito window and go to https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d2013853-Reviews-114_Faubourg-Paris_Ile_de_France.html?filterLang=ALL the reviews look like exactly like in your post. Then, if you refresh the page, the reviews are correct. It has to do with cookies that are being set for the first time and a session mecanism. I didn't investigate further because there was an easier way to proceed (and in a single request).

Comment: @denis It's probably a bug in the UI or server side if it was behaving differently before